# Apex Testing Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts

Tags: apex

```
@isTest
public with sharing class ContactTriggerHandlerTest {
    @isTest
    public static void afterInsertHandlerTest() {
        List<Account> testAccounts = new List<Account>();
        testAccounts.add(new Account(Name = 'Test 11'));
        testAccounts.add(new Account(Name = 'Test 22'));

        Test.startTest();
        insert testAccounts;
        Test.stopTest();
   }
}
```

I dont know why im getting a "Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts" error when running test.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest();`, async code (@future, batchable, queueable, schedulable) is caused to run after `Test.stopTest();`

So through some path of execution, your account insertion is causing a callout to happen (through some async apex, because callouts can't be made from a trigger context).

Using `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` is good practice, and you should keep using them. To work around this error, you'll need to implement `HttpCalloutMock`. See [Testing HTTP Callouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing.htm) for more details on that.

Comment: hi derek thanks for the reply but even if I remove the Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest() im still getting the same error this issue occur when I use a DML statements in Apex Testing.